# Javascript : How to find the class instance of a method only from a pointer to this method

Tags: javascript, class, methods, owner

I have a class instance with some method. If I only have a pointer to this method, how to find a pointer to its parent class instance ?

My goal here is to do an automatic bind() when dealing with eventListeners.

A simplfied version of my current source code looks like this :

```
function CreateListener(domElement , type , callback){
    domElement.addEventListener(type , callback);
}

var MyClass = function(){
    this.name = "Bob";
    CreateListener(document.body , "mousedown" , this.OnMouseDownCallback.bind(this) );
};
MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass;

MyClass.prototype.OnMouseDownCallback = function(event){
    console.log("YAY !" , this.name);
};

var MyInstance = new MyClass();
```

I would like to do something like this :

```
function CreateListener(domElement , type , callback){

    // I want to to the binding HERE,
    // only using the callback variable in some way,
    // to find a pointer to MyInstance and use it in place of the "???"

    domElement.addEventListener(type , callback.bind( ??? ) );
}

var MyClass = function(){
    this.name = "Bob";
    CreateListener(document.body , "mousedown" , this.OnMouseDownCallback);
};
MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass;

MyClass.prototype.OnMouseDownCallback = function(event){
    console.log("YAY !" , this.name);
};

var MyInstance = new MyClass();
```

After many searches... I'm starting to think this is not possible at all :/
But any hint, workaround or other idea will be welcomed !

Comment: I can think of es6 Proxy as a possible direction. [Docs for 'get' method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get). If you wrap instances into proxies you'll have access to each proxy as a `receiver` parameter of `get` method. But I think it's a bad design to start with, if you need such hacks.

Comment: What JS/ES version are you targeting? Are you using any preprocessors? I'm wondering why you write your classes like this, and don't use the sugar. I'd approach the problem differently, by writing a decorator that binds the method to the instance when it is accessed for the first time.

Comment: @wostex : here I want the scope to stay inside the class instance when the eventListener trigger the callback method, so I have to do the binding (I don't know a better way to do this).
I don't "really" need this hack, I'm just looking for a way to simplify the syntax by not having to type the binding part.

Comment: @Thomas
I'm targeting ES5 for now... but maybe I should switch to ES6...
Have you any suggestion for a cleaner way to write classes with ES5 ? And do You mind showing me an example of the decorator you are suggesting please ?